# Get dates within the range of last week, this week, next week - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my Task sheet I have Column A with dates in each cell. Each row corresponds to a task.

My intention is:

Based on the current date, that is, today's date that is obtained automatically, I conclude the dates of the range of the past week, the range of the current week and the range of the next week.

Always from Monday to Sunday, two days included. (here is Spain the week starts on Monday).

Once this is done, I perform a forEach and an IF conditional to loop through each row in column A to:

1. Get all the tasks in which the dates of the cells in column A are between Monday and Sunday of the last week and do X thing.
2. Get all the tasks where the dates in the cells of column A are between Monday and Sunday of this current week and do X thing.
3. Get all the tasks in which the dates in the cells of column A are between Monday and Sunday of the next week and do X thing.

With this code I had managed to make it work well except for two problems that I have encountered.

1. I get the dates that were within each range, except Monday! The date of each cell that coincided with Monday could not be obtained. This can be checked with the Logger.log inside forEach.
   Screenshot here: https://ibb.co/SPzgYK3
2. On the other hand, I have verified that if the current day (today) is Sunday, then all the relative dates of the week of the GetRelativeDayInWeek function return the date of last Monday. For example, today Sunday 12/02, then the return of the relative day of the week was all Monday 06/02. Therefore with this problem, all my code stops working correctly.
   Screenshot here: https://ibb.co/bRcr96R

As much as I have searched, observed and looked at my code and the possible problem, I cannot understand where the error is. I am new to this.
Somebody could help me?

```
function weekDatesRange() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(' Todos los eventos');
     
    // Obtener la fecha de hoy (Get today date)
      var hoy = new Date();
      var hoyFormatted = hoy.toDateString();
      Logger.log(hoy);
      Logger.log(hoyFormatted);

    // Returns the relative day in the week 0 = Domingo pasado, 1 = Lunes ... 6 = Sabado, 7 = Proximo Domingo

      function getRelativeDayInWeek2(d,dy) {
        d = new Date(d);
        var day = d.getDay(),
            diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:dy); // adjust when day is sunday

            d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            
        return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
      }

      var lunesPasado = getRelativeDayInWeek2(new Date(),-6);  // Last Monday
      var domingoPasado = getRelativeDayInWeek2(new Date(),0);  // Last Sunday
      var lunes = getRelativeDayInWeek2(new Date(),1);  // This Monday
      var domingo = getRelativeDayInWeek2(new Date(),7);  // This Sunday
      var proximoLunes = getRelativeDayInWeek2(new Date(),8);  // Next Monday
      var proximoDomingo = getRelativeDayInWeek2(new Date(),14);  // Next Sunday


      Logger.log('LAST MONDAY: ' + lunesPasado);
      Logger.log('LAST SUNDAY: ' + domingoPasado);
      Logger.log('MONDAY: ' + lunes);
      Logger.log('SUNDAY: ' + domingo);
      Logger.log('NEXT MONDAY: ' + proximoLunes);
      Logger.log('NEXT SUNDAY: ' + proximoDomingo);

    // Obtenemos cada fila de la columna A (Fecha) y ejecutamos la condicional IF. - Get Rows of Column A (Date) and run the conditional IF.

      const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      const lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var rango = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow -1, lastCol);
      var values = rango.getValues();
    
      values.forEach((fila) => {

        if (fila[0] >= lunesPasado && fila[0] <= domingoPasado) {  // Semana pasada (Last week)
            Logger.log(fila[0].toDateString() + '  --->  ' + 'Esta tarea fué la semana PASADA - Last Week');
        } else if (fila[0] >= lunes && fila[0] <= domingo) {  // Semana actual (This week)
            Logger.log(fila[0].toDateString() + '  --->  ' + 'Esta tarea será ESTA semana - This Week');
        } else if (fila[0] >= proximoLunes && fila[0] <= proximoDomingo) {  // Proxima semana (Next week)
            Logger.log(fila[0].toDateString() + '  --->  ' + 'Esta tarea será la PROXIMA semana - Next Week');
        }

        // Dates of last week, this week and next week to compare with the result of Logger.log
        // 30/01 - 05/02 Last Week
        // 06/02 - 12/02 This week
        // 13/02 - 19/02 Next week
      
      })    
    
  }
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I have answered you below the comment of your script. Can you take a look please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another approach for retrieving the last week, this week, and next week, how about the following modification? In this modification, the first, the 1st, and last days (Monday and Sunday) of this week are retrieved. And, the last week and the next week are retrieved using these values.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  // Create an object including the last week, this week, and next week.
  const now = new Date();
  const year = now.getFullYear();
  const month = now.getMonth();
  const first = now.getDate() - now.getDay() + 1;
  const last = first + 6;
  const obj = {
    lastWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first - 7).getTime(),
    lastWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last - 7).getTime(),
    thisWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first).getTime(),
    thisWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last).getTime(),
    nextWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first + 7).getTime(),
    nextWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last + 7).getTime(),
  };

  // Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const [, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Split rows for the last week, this week, and next week.
  const res = values.reduce((o, r) => {
    const t = r[0].getTime();
    ["last", "this", "next"].forEach(e => {
      if (t >= obj[`${e}WeekFirstDay`] && t < obj[`${e}WeekLastDay`]) {
        o[`${e}Week`].push(r);
      }
    });
    return o;
  }, { lastWeek: [], thisWeek: [], nextWeek: [] });
  console.log(res);
}
```

- When this script is run today (2023-02-13), `obj` is as follows. In this case, even when the script is run as today of 2023-02-12, the same result is obtained.

  ```json
  {
    "lastWeekFirstDay":"Mon Feb 06 2023",
    "lastWeekLastDay":"Sun Feb 12 2023",
    "thisWeekFirstDay":"Mon Feb 13 2023",
    "thisWeekLastDay":"Sun Feb 19 2023",
    "nextWeekFirstDay":"Mon Feb 20 2023",
    "nextWeekLastDay":"Sun Feb 26 2023"
  }
  ```
- And, `res` is as follows. Each value is the matched rows for the last week, this week, and next week.

  ```json
  {
    "lastWeek":[[,,,], [,,,],,,],
    "thisWeek":[[,,,], [,,,],,,],
    "nextWeek":[[,,,], [,,,],,,],
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: First of all, I apologize for not answering sooner. I'm sorry! Your code works fine, it gets me the rows from last week, this week and next week. However, I can't manage to do a conditional if for each of these results.

Comment: `var valLastWeek = res.lastWeek;
  var rango = sheet.getDataRange();
  
  valLastWeek.forEach((fila)=> {

      fila[11] = 'yes';
 
  })
  rango.setValues(valLastWeek);
  valLastWeek.insertCheckboxes('yes');` I get an error  **"Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 3 but the range has 18."**

Comment: For the rows returned by res.lastWeek I need "yes" to be placed on those rows returned but in column 11 (L). For res.thisWeek the same, but it would be in column 12 (M). For res.nextWeek it would be in column 13(N). So that later with .insertCheckbox('yes') get the checkbox to be checked.

Comment: I've even tried with:  `var rango = sheet.getRange(2, 1, valLastWeek.length, sheet.getLastColumn());` but i keep getting error:  **Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets**

Comment: @Nerea Thank you for replying. From `Your code works fine, it gets me the rows from last week, this week and next week.`, I understood my script was resolved your question. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand `However, I can't manage to do a conditional if for each of these results.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Nerea About `For the rows returned by res.lastWeek I need "yes" to be placed on those rows returned`, I cannot find this in your question. Where can I see it in your question? I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Here is an image with a clear explanation:  https://ibb.co/d78vyBY    Here is the link of the modified code:  https://jsfiddle.net/neo7Lx4g/2/   And here the result of the console when I execute the modified code:  https://ibb.co/23DZCp0

Comment: @Nerea Thank you for replying. I have 3 questions. 1. You cannot provide a sample Spreadsheet for testing your current issue. Is my understanding correct? 2. About `For the rows returned by res.lastWeek I need "yes" to be placed on those rows returned`, I cannot find this in your question. Where can I see it in your question? 3. From your question, I understood that you wanted to retrieve the last week, this week, and the next week from column "A". Is my understanding correct? From your reply, I'm worried that you might have changed your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Nerea By the way, your script below `//-------   From here my modification.   -------` of [https://jsfiddle.net/neo7Lx4g/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/neo7Lx4g/2/) is a new question? Unfortunately, I cannot find this in your question. If my understanding is correct, I would like to recommend splitting the question between 1st question and 2nd question. Because I think that from `Your code works fine, it gets me the rows from last week, this week and next week.`, your 1st question has been resolved. I'm confused about your reply. If my understanding of your question was not correct, I apologize.

Comment: This is part of my original question: https://ibb.co/PwCbRr6   In fact in my original code it includes the forEach loop and the IF conditionals.
Should I perhaps open a new question for this particular issue?

Comment: @Nerea Thank you for replying. About `do X thing`, in your question, I cannot understand the detail of `do X thing`. In this case, it is required to know it. If you want to add `do X thing` as a new question, I agree with `Should I perhaps open a new question for this particular issue?`. In that case, please close this question. And, when you posted it as a new question, I would like to support it. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Ok, No problem, I'll create a new question then.I thought it was all the same question, but on second thought, I suppose you are right and two different questions could be considered.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Heres is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454929/get-exception-service-error-spreadsheets-in-range-setvalues-google-apps-sc