# Get "Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets" in range.setValues() Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**My objective:**

1. I get the rows where the date in column A is between Monday and Sunday of "Last Week".
2. Created a forEach array where I added the value "yes" to the cells in column L that correspond to the previously returned rows.
3. I insert a checkbox in the whole column L (only in the rows that contain data), and make the checkboxes where the cells contain "yes" be checked.

This process is repeated for "Last week", "This week", "Next week".

**What's my problem:**

The problem I have is that when I run this script, I get an error "Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets" specifically in the code part `rango.setValues(valLastWeek);`  `rango.setValues(valThisWeek);`  `rango.setValues(valNextWeek);`

I've searched for solutions here on stackoverflow but can't fix the problem. I have tried adding more rows, trying to find a problem with my code,... but I can't find the solution to my problem.

Here I leave a screenshot of what I want. https://ibb.co/d78vyBY

Here you have a sample sheet to reproduce the problem with the code already embedded in GAS: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D7DsMyGnXQlOY-hL9kkZsOml7xAoJDMNA2-uIYM8m3Y/edit?usp=sharing

**This is my complete code:**

```
function weeksRange() {
  const sheetName = ' Todos los eventos'; // Please set your sheet name.

  // Create an object including the last week, this week, and next week.
      const now = new Date();
      const year = now.getFullYear();
      const month = now.getMonth();
      const first = now.getDate() - now.getDay() + 1;
      const last = first + 6;
      const obj = {
        lastWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first - 7).getTime(),
        lastWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last - 7).getTime(),
        thisWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first).getTime(),
        thisWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last).getTime(),
        nextWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first + 7).getTime(),
        nextWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last + 7).getTime(),
      };

  // Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      const [, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

      // Split rows for the last week, this week, and next week.
          const res = values.reduce((o, r) => {
            const t = r[0].getTime();
            ["last", "this", "next"].forEach(e => {
              if (t >= obj[`${e}WeekFirstDay`] && t < obj[`${e}WeekLastDay`]) {
                o[`${e}Week`].push(r);
              }
            });
            return o;
          }, { lastWeek: [], thisWeek: [], nextWeek: [] });
          console.log(res);

  // LAST WEEK
      var valLastWeek = res.lastWeek;
      Logger.log(res.lastWeek);

      var totalFilasLastWeek = valLastWeek.length;
      var totalColLastWeek = valLastWeek[0].length;
      var rango = sheet.getRange(2, 1, totalFilasLastWeek, totalColLastWeek);
      
      valLastWeek.forEach((fila)=> {
        Logger.log(fila);
          fila[11] = 'yes';
          //Logger.log(fila[11]);
      })
      rango.setValues(valLastWeek);
      valLastWeek.insertCheckboxes('yes');
    
  // THIS WEEK
      var valThisWeek = res.thisWeek;
      Logger.log(res.thisWeek);

      var totalFilasThisWeek = valThisWeek.length;
      var totalColThisWeek = valThisWeek[0].length;      
      var rango = sheet.getRange(2, 1, totalFilasThisWeek, totalColThisWeek);
      
      valThisWeek.forEach((fila)=> {
        Logger.log(fila);
          fila[12] = 'yes';
      })
      rango.setValues(valThisWeek);
      valThisWeek.insertCheckboxes('yes');
      
  // NEXT WEEK
      var valNextWeek = res.nextWeek;
      Logger.log(res.nextWeek);

      var totalFilasNextWeek = valNextWeek.length;
      var totalColNextWeek = valNextWeek[0].length;
      var rango = sheet.getRange(2, 1, totalFilasNextWeek, totalColNextWeek);
      
      valNextWeek.forEach((fila)=> {
        Logger.log(fila);
          fila[13] = 'yes';   
      })
      rango.setValues(valNextWeek);
      valNextWeek.insertCheckboxes('yes');
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your script and spreadsheet and your expected result, I thought that in this case, the row number might be suitable instead of the row values. So, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function weeksRange() {
  const sheetName = ' Todos los eventos'; // Please set your sheet name.

  // Create an object including the last week, this week, and next week.
  const now = new Date();
  const year = now.getFullYear();
  const month = now.getMonth();
  const first = now.getDate() - now.getDay() + 1;
  const last = first + 6;
  const obj = {
    lastWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first - 7).getTime(),
    lastWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last - 7).getTime(),
    thisWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first).getTime(),
    thisWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last).getTime(),
    nextWeekFirstDay: new Date(year, month, first + 7).getTime(),
    nextWeekLastDay: new Date(year, month, last + 7).getTime(),
  };

  // Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const [, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Split rows for the last week, this week, and next week.
  const res = values.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    const t = r[0].getTime();
    ["last", "this", "next"].forEach(e => {
      if (t >= obj[`${e}WeekFirstDay`] && t < obj[`${e}WeekLastDay`]) {
        o[`${e}Week`].push(i + 2); // Modified
      }
    });
    return o;
  }, { lastWeek: [], thisWeek: [], nextWeek: [] });
  console.log(res);


  // I modified the below script.
  const ranges = [...res.lastWeek.map(r => `L${r}`), ...res.thisWeek.map(r => `M${r}`), ...res.nextWeek.map(r => `N${r}`)];
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).check();
}
```

- In this modification, `console.log(res);` shows the row numbers of each value. Using this value, as a sample, `var v = res.lastWeek;` is used as "LAST WEEK". When this script is run, the checkboxes of column "L" are checked and the value of "yes" is set for the rows of "LAST WEEK".
- When you check "THIS WEEK", please use `var v = res.thisWeek;` instead of `var v = res.lastWeek;`.

Comment: I think I misphrased my question. Rows returned from **"Last Week"** should have the checkbox checked in **column L**. Rows returned from **"This Week"** in **col. M**. Rows from **"Next Week"** in **col. N**. I more or less understand your code, however, I cannot locate where you are indicating in which column to check the checkbox.

Comment: The approach of getting the row number instead of the data is perfect. I had not thought of it.

Comment: There is an error with your last modification. The line ```sheet.getRangeList(ranges).check();``` should be changed to ```sheet.getRangeList(ranges).insertCheckboxes("yes").check();```   Otherwise it works great! Now I know where the column is mentioned! Just on ```(r => `L${r}`)``` the L is what is changed by the letter of the column that you want. I didn't notice that before. I suppose that being at dawn and not sleeping also affects my view. Thank you very much for your support. Again I have learned something new :)